# Remove even amounts of duplicates from an array

Tags: arrays, perl, duplicates

I have an array

```
[ 1, 0, 0, 0, 5, 2, 4, 5, 2, 2 ]
```

I need to delete even amounts of duplicates.

That means, if a value appears an even number of times in the array then remove them all, but if it appears an odd number of times then keep just one.

The result from the array above should be

```
[ 1, 0, 2, 4 ]
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This really isn't difficult, and it is very bad form to show no attempt at all at solving it yourself. I would like someone who posted questions like this to describe how they feel comfortable getting someone else to do their work for them. Even difficult crosswords don't get this flood of requests for a solution, but in this case presumably you are being paid for a solution written by someone else? Why is that not a problem to you?

- Build a hash to calculate the current count for each value
- use `$_ % 2` do determine the new final count
- Deconstruct the hash to a new array

```
my $array = [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 5, 2, 4, 5, 2, 2 ];

my @new_array = do {

    my %counts;

    ++$counts{$_} for @$array;

    map {
        ( $_ ) x ( $counts{$_} % 2 )
    } sort { $a <=> $b } keys %counts;
};

use Data::Dump;
dd \@new_array;
```

#### output

```
[0, 1, 2, 4]
```

Comment: Perhaps track indices (`0..$#array`) instead, so to keep the order?  Anyway, I wish that your opening paragraph is etched on top of every page here.

Comment: @zdim: There's becoming a division between advocates of my sentiment and others who think it is out of line with the Stack Overflow ***Be Nice*** policy. I am certain that simply giving all questioners everything they ask for is not useful to anyone. Some of the reasons are considered in a new blog post [*Stack Overflow Isn’t Very Welcoming. It’s Time for That to Change.*](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/) and I suggest that you take a look. It looks like things I've seen several times already, but any hew hope is worthwhile.

Comment: @zdim: That sounds possible. If, instead of the actual value, the hash used the index of the first occurrence of that value in the array, we could retain the order. I may write that tomorrow but I should be asleep right now. Please post your own answer if you feel so inclined.

Comment: @zdim: If you're interested then your English should look like *", I wish that your opening paragraph* ***were*** *etched on top of every page here"*. It's a very common mistake, even amongst native English speakers, but people usually choose ***was***, rather than ***is***.

Comment: Very interested and thank you very much for correcting me. I wish my language weren't affected when I am tired; I've known my conditionals and tenses for some 20 years now :(. (Interestingly, I read over that sentence a few times. It was itching.)

Comment: Yeah, be nice. I am all for being nice and I hope that my posts show that.  (As for the article, there'd be a lot to discuss there. Thank you.) While it does bother me when questions are treated with hostility, sarcasm & Co., there is so much more to it. For one, we are swamped by brutal attempts  to simply extract something. On the other hand, many honestly don't realize what they are doing when they ask and _telling them that_ may well be useful for them.  So I think that we should say what need be said. It will help a lot if the site improves in this regard.

Comment: @zdim: I thought you'd want to know. There aren't many people whom I'd correct like that, but you are always careful with your written English.

Answer (score 5):

Removing duplicates is usually done as follows:

```
use List::Util 1.44 qw( uniqnum );

@a = uniqnum @a;
```

or

```
my %seen;
@a = grep { !$seen{$_}++ } @a;
```

---

To achieve what you want, we simply need chain `grep` that removes the other undesired elements.

```
use List::Util 1.44 qw( uniqnum );

@a = uniqnum grep { $counts{$_} % 2 } @a;
```

or

```
my %seen;
@a = grep { !$seen{$_}++ } grep { $counts{$_} % 2 } @a;
```

or

```
my %seen;
@a = grep { ( $counts{$_} % 2 ) && !$seen{$_}++ } @a;
```

---

The above solutions rely on having the count of each value. To obtain that, we can use the following:

```
my %counts;
++$counts{$_} for @a;
```

---

All together:

```
my ( %counts, %seen );
++$counts{$_} for @a;
@a = grep { ( $counts{$_} % 2 ) && !$seen{$_}++ } @a;
```

Note that these methods of removing duplicates preserve the order of the elements (keeping the first duplicate). This is more efficient (O(N)) then involving `sort` (O(N log N)) to avoid producing something non-deterministic.

Answer (score 1):

See the comments, to see how this possible solution does it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @a = qw(1 0 0 0 5 2 4 5 2 2);

# Move through the array.
for (my $i = 0; $i < scalar(@a); ) {
  # Move through the positions at and ahead of current position $i
  # and collect all positions $j, that share the value at the
  # current position $i.
  my @indexes;
  for (my $j = $i; $j < scalar(@a); $j++) {
    if ($a[$j] == $a[$i]) {
      push(@indexes, $j);
    }
  }

  if (scalar(@indexes) % 2) {
    # If the number of positions collected is odd remove the first
    # position from the collection. The number of positions in the
    # collection is then even afterwards.
    shift(@indexes);
    # As we will keep the value at the current position $i no new
    # value will move into that position. Hence we have to advance
    # the current position.
    $i++;
  }

  # Move through the collected positions.
  for (my $k = 0; $k < scalar(@indexes); $k++) {
    # Remove the element at the position as indicated by the
    # $k'th element of the collect positions.
    # We have to subtract $k from the collected position, to
    # compensate for the movement of the remaining elements to the
    # left.
    splice(@a, $indexes[$k] - $k, 1);
  }
}

print("@a");
```

Comment: "ahead of" (and "behind") are ambiguous when dealing with iterators: *before* and *after* usually fare better.

Comment: It is best to replace `for ( my $i = 0; $i < scalar(@a); ) { ... }` with `my $i = 0; while ( $i < @a ) { ... }`. The missing third clause of the `for` will rarely be noticed by even the best engineers.

Answer (score 0):

You have a bunch of answers, here's another:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $input = [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 5, 2, 4, 5, 2, 2 ];
my $output = dedupe_evens($input);

print Data::Dumper->Dump([$input, $output], ['$input', '$output']);

exit;


sub dedupe_evens {
    my($input) = @_;

    my %seen;
    $seen{$_}++ foreach @$input;
    my @output = grep {
        my $count = delete $seen{$_};  # only want first occurrence
        $count && $count % 2;
    } @$input;

    return \@output;
}
```

Which produces this output (reformatted for brevity):

```
$input  = [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 5, 2, 4, 5, 2, 2 ];
$output = [ 1, 0, 2, 4 ];
```